# Passing variable from Controller to Route, and then View

Tags: laravel, routes

I have my `$user` variable in my controller, and I want to redirect to a route with passing the $user  variable. In the route, all I am doing is returning the view.

This is how I return from my controller:

`return  Redirect::route('welcome')->with('user',$user);`

And my route looks like this:

```
Route::get('welcome', array('as' => 'welcome', function() {
   return view('main');
}));
```

Or for example, if I want to return a boolean variable just to know user is just signed up or not (so for example, I can show them welcome popup), what should I do?

What is the best way to pass the `$user` variable to my view?

---

I know I can directly use `return view('main')->with(['user' => $user]);` but this leaves the link ugly.

Comment: You may pass the user ID instead to the route. like `return  Redirect::route('welcome/' . $user->id)` and it will result in `http://website.com/welcome/1`. Then from 1, you can get the user. The link is less ugly.

Comment: put your variable in session.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just trying to pass data to another view without passing it through the url. You can work with session. If sign up was ok, save in a session like this:
`session(['signedup' => true]);`

Then in your welcome page, get it like
    `$isSignedUp = session('signedup');`

From there, you can do anything with `$isSignedUp` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
return Redirect::to('/welcome?user='. $user);
```

**OR**

```
return view('welcome',compact('user'));
```

Hope this work for you!